# Writing an uncertainty of the form $8.3\pm1.2$ using 'parenthesis' notation similar to $5.9722(6)$

Tags: experimental-physics, conventions, notation, error-analysis

It's common in the physical sciences to write dimensional quantities with their 1-sigma uncertainty range as, e.g.:
$$
M_\oplus=5.9722(6)\times10^{24} \; \mathrm{kg}
$$

However, I'm having a disagreement with a colleague over what to do in the situation where the number you're quoting only has 1 d.p. For example, I want to express $h = (8.3 \pm 1.2) \; \mathrm{m}$. I think I should do so like this:
$$
h = 8.3(12) \; \mathrm{m}
$$

She thinks I should do so like this:
$$
h = 8.3(1.2) \; \mathrm{m}
$$

Which of us is right, is this a matter of opinion and, most importantly, can you provide a reference to an authoritive style guide, etc. on the subject?

Comment: There is probably a standards document (or possibly more than one) that addresses this issue. I have an opinion on the matter and a reason for that opinion, but it is based on a verbal interpretation of this convention for which I have no reference.

Comment: Even if you *do* find an authoritative style guide, how clear (and how distracting) will the notation be to your readers? That needs to be weighed against the possible (dis)advantages of simply using $(8.3\pm1.2) \:\rm m$; it's a tiny bit wordsier but the number isn't that big anyways.

Comment: Absolutely, the fact that we had this discussion has persuaded me to use the $\pm$ format instead. However I'm still curious if a convention exists.

Comment: The parentheses notation is usually reserved for high precision situations where writing something like $3.141592654 \pm 0.00000047$ is really cumbersome. In the case you're working with, $8.3\pm 1.2$ is probably better for being more clear, and is a comparable amount of writing. Point being: when the answer matters, it's the wrong way to write the precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both forms are correct, but the uncertainty is rarely if ever reported in an abbreviated form in cases like that of your example. The first form is definitely ambiguous and can be easily mistaken. The second one is less ambiguous, but not well known (it's correct anyhow, see the [*Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement*, §7.2.2, point 3](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf#page=38)).

Thus, you're both right, but, generally speaking, I'd avoid ambiguous forms.

Comment: Thanks for finding that guide, it’s exactly what I was looking for. I agree completely that, since the job of a piece of scientific literature is to communicate clearly, both these forms should be avoided here since there’s obvious room for misinterpretation either way.

Comment: I don't think the BIPM guide provides an answer to this question. This question is asking about the uncertainty formatting where, for uncertainties less than 1.0, the leading zeros and decimal point are trimmed from the uncertainty, then the remaining string is put in parentheses. The question is, if the uncertainty is greater than 1.0, should we remove the decimal point even though it is to the right of the most significant digit in the uncertainty. The BIPM guide does not address that example. 7.2.2 point 2 is the relevant one, but it has an uncertainty <1.0.

Comment: 7.2.2 point 3, referenced in this answer, is not using the formatting style where leading zeros (and decimal symbol) are stripped, so that point doesn't bear on this question.

Answer (score 1):

When analyzing a reported value and trying to determine what is significant, all nonzero digits are significant, and it is only zeros that require some thought. We will use the terms “leading,” “trailing,” and “captive” for the zeros and will consider how to deal with them. Source: https://opentextbc.ca/chemistry/chapter/measurement-uncertainty-accuracy-and-precision/.

[image: Leading, captive and trailing zeros]

**I agree with your friend, use 1.2**, not your value. In cases where only the decimal-formatted number is available, it is prudent to assume that all trailing zeros are not significant.

[image: Standard Deviation]
The probabilities of a value lying within 1-sigma, 2-sigma and 3-sigma of the mean for a normal distribution.

The significance of various levels of $\sigma$, or confidence that result is real: 1 $\sigma$ 84.13%, 1.5 $\sigma$ 93.32%, 2 $\sigma$ 97.73%, 2.5 $\sigma$ 99.38%, 3 $\sigma$ 99.87%, 3.5 $\sigma$ 99.98%, 4 $\sigma$ 100%. Source: https://thecuriousastronomer.wordpress.com/2014/06/26/what-does-a-1-sigma-3-sigma-or-5-sigma-detection-mean/.

Note: When determining significant figures, be sure to pay attention to reported values and think about the measurement and significant figures in terms of what is reasonable or likely when evaluating whether the value makes sense. For example, the official January 2014 census reported the resident population of the US as 317,297,725. Do you think the US population was correctly determined to the reported nine significant figures, that is, to the exact number of people? People are constantly being born, dying, or moving into or out of the country, and assumptions are made to account for the large number of people who are not actually counted. Because of these uncertainties, it might be more reasonable to expect that we know the population to within perhaps a million or so, in which case the population should be reported as 3.17 × 10$^8$ people.

There are many fields where [allowance and tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance#Mechanical_component_tolerance) is a factor and Standards were created, currently the "ISO Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement" (GUM) and the NIST TN 1297 (Section 7: Reporting Uncertainty) are [what is followed](https://users.physics.unc.edu/~deardorf/uncertainty/UNCguide.html).

Source: http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/p510/w/images/p510/b/b7/Lecture_3_S11.pdf

**Different Types of Uncertainties**

- Random/Statistical  (All)

  Always  present  in a measurement.  It  is  caused  by  inherently unpredictable  fluctuations  in the readings  of  a measurement apparatus  or  in the  experimenter's  interpretation  of  the instrumental  reading.  Originates  in the  Poisson  distribution.
- Systematic  (All)

  From  imperfect  calibration  of  measurement  instruments,  or imperfect  methods  of  observation,  or  interference  of  the environment  with  the  measurement  process.  Always  affect the  results  of  an  experiment  in a predictable  direction. e.g.  zero  setting  error  in  which  the  instrument  does  not  read zero  when  the  quantity  to  be  measured  is  zero
- Theory  (e.g.  N15,  N17)

  In  these  experiments  you  measure  the  muon  lifetime.  But  there are  corrections  to  the  capture  rate  for  muon  that  come  from theory.

**Different Types of Uncertainties**

It  is common to  quote  these  uncertainties  separately:

τ$_μ$=(2.19+/-0.05$_{stat.}$+/-0.01$_{syst.}$+/-0.02$_{th.}$) $μ$s

Different notations  are used  for  uncertainties,  e.g.

τ$_μ$=(2.19(5)$_{stat.}$+/-(1)$_{syst.}$+/-(2)$_{th.}$) $μ$s

**Meaning  of Measurement  Uncertainty**

• If  we  measure  for example  a  voltage  V = 10.2 +/- 0.3 V, what  does  this  mean?

• In  general  there  are differences  in  different science disciplines.

• In physics, a  1-sigma  uncertainty  is  generally  used. If  the measurements  are normally  distributed  (Gaussian), this corresponds  to a  68% confidence  level  (CL)  interval.  Or that  32% of the  time the true  value  would  be outside  the quoted  uncertainty range.

**Semantics**

- Accuracy  vs. Precision

  Accuracy  is the  degree  to which a measurement  agrees  with  the true  value.

  Precision  is the  repeatability of the  measurement.
- Error vs. Uncertainty

  Error  is the  degree  to  which  a Measurement  agrees  with  the true  value.

  Uncertainty  is an  interval  around  the  measurement  in  which  repeated measurements  will  fall.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at NIST and BIPM guides and I do not think there is currently (June 2023) any authoritative reference that gives a recommendation for what to do for this example. The relevant point from BIPM appears in https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/2071204/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf/cb0ef43f-baa5-11cf-3f85-4dcd86f77bd6#page=38, 7.2.2 point 2.

> “$m_S$ = 100,021 47(35) g, where the number in parentheses is the numerical value of (the combined
> standard uncertainty) $u_c$ referred to the corresponding last digits of the quoted result.”

Here the value of physical quantity is 100.02147 g (I'm using a period as decimal symbol instead of a comma like in the quote) and the uncertainty 0.00035 g = 0.35 mg = 350 ug.

You can see they took 0.00035 g and left-stripped leading zeros and the decimal symbol to get (35)

But what if the uncertainty were 3.5 mg instead. Should we have

100.0(3.5)

or

100.0(35)

The problem is, it is not clear what "referred to the corresponding last digits of the quoted result" means. I interpret it to mean: line the right most digit of the uncertainty in parentheses up right the right most digit of the value, now add a decimal point in the same spot as the value (if it's not there already), and add zeros between the leftmost digit of the uncertainty and the decimal point if there are empty spaces. If there's nothing to the left of the decimal point add a zero.
This is the algorithm to recover a regular decimal representation of the uncertainty from the parentheses notation.

I don't like having mentally add the uncertainty somewhere in the middle of the uncertainty to figure out its magnitude. Consider

1234.89 +/- 78.23

1234.89(78.23)

vs

1234.89(7823)

I've got to break in favor of the former.