# Shorthand error notation (with brackets) accros decimal point

Tags: experimental-physics, notation, error-analysis

I have a small doubt regarding the use of shorthand error notation, i.e. $6.626070150(81)$ instead of $6.626070150 \pm 0.000000081$.

When the error has 2 s.f. (such as when the error is just over $1 \cdot 10^n$) and in the units used, the error is "1 point something", for example: $11.5\pm 1.2$.

Would 11.5(1.2) be correct, or is this notation only valid for scientific notation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing an uncertainty of the form $8.3\pm1.2$ using 'parenthesis' notation similar to $5.9722(6)$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/378194/writing-an-uncertainty-of-the-form-8-3-pm1-2-using-parenthesis-notation-simi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Info/Constants/definitions.html, the notation should perhaps rather be

$11.5\pm 1.2 = 11.5 (12)$

because

> the number in parentheses is the numerical value of the standard uncertainty referred to the corresponding last digits of the quoted result.

The uncertainty in the example is 12 times the value of the last digit,  12 tenths or 1.2.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) from the quoted passage that 11.5(12) is preferred over 11.5(1.2)... "referred to the corresponding last digits" is not precise enough to choose between the two in my opinion. Not to mention this answer is in disagreement with the answers in the question that this one duplicates.